# Using external plugins in Sencha Touch

Tags: sencha-touch, extjs, sencha-touch-2

I want to use a simple Sencha Touch keypad plugin. 
The plugin code can be found over [here](https://github.com/msmeeks/sencha-keypad).
The keypad can be created in an html file under  tags as follows:

```
<script>
    Ext.setup({
        onReady: function () {
            var basic = new Ext.ux.Keypad();
            basic.render('keypad');
        }
     });
</script>

<div id="keypad"/>
```

Alternatively, it can be used in a Sencha container as follows too:

```
...
items:[
    {
        xtype: 'keypad'
    }
]
```

However, I am not able to get it to work the latter way. I'm new to Sencha and I think I'm not placing the files at the right places or not including them properly. I have already included the following in my index.html:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="js/sencha-touch-1.1.1/sencha-touch.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="js/sencha-touch-1.1.1/resources/css/sencha-touch.css">
<script src="js/Keypad.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

Can someone let me know what modifications are necessary in which files so that I can use the keypad plugin directly in a container?

Answer (score 1):

in your app.js file you need to set path for the plugin folder in the loader...
put the ux (plugin)folder where your app.js is located...
in app.js set the following

```
Ext.Loader.setPath('Ext.ux', 'ux');
```

On the view where you are using the numpad you need to specify a

```
requires: ['Ext.ux.NumPad' ...] //All plugin related files
```

Also ensure that the CSS files are in the proper location...
Hope it helps...